# Add Intellij IDEA runtime assertion feature in Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception, annotations

There's a feature in Intellij IDEA:

> Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Add runtime assertions for
>   non-null-annotated methods and parameters

which injects null-checking wherever is needed.
I'd like to have the same feature while building using Maven. Is there any simple way to have this in Maven as plugin or something?

I found [intellij-annotations-instrumenter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/VladRassokhin/intellij-annotations-instrumenter-maven-plugin) which seems to be what I'm looking for (is that right?), but it has its last commit on Oct 9, 2013.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a forked version of the repo you mentioned which I believe does what you want (along with some other useful additions). It's latest release was in September 2016 https://github.com/osundblad/intellij-annotations-instrumenter-maven-plugin

It's also widely publshed as a maven artifact https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/se.eris/notnull-instrumenter-maven-plugin